# Python coordinate rotations becoming smaller with iterations

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, trigonometry, cartesian-coordinates

I am having an issue with my coordinates becoming infinitesimally smaller as my program iterates through the coordinate rotation algorithm. I have put a gif below that showcases this in a slower framerate; as it continues the line eventually disappears.

https://i.gyazo.com/368fbc65dbc5d3deaa282a4b72ec5d22.mp4

I think the issue is with the sin and cos possibly truncating numbers but I am not sure

```
def run(root, canvas, line, x, y, width, height):
    # counter clockwise rotation of cartesian coordinates
    # X =  xcosθ + ysinθ
    # Y = -xsinθ + ycosθ

    theta = 1/8

    x, y = tk_to_cart(width/2, height/2, x, y)

    x =  x * cos(theta) + y * sin(theta)
    y = -x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta)

    x, y = cart_to_tk(width/2, height/2, x, y)

    canvas.delete(line)
    line = canvas.create_line(width/2, height/2, x, y)

    root.after(20, lambda: run(root, canvas, line, x, y, width, height))
```

tk_to_cart and cart_to_tk are just simple translations across the canvas because of tkinter's coordinate system having 0,0 in the top left.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the solution, but maybe your rotation script is wrong. Check out this website: https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/ . It seems different from yours.

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 That formula is just for going counter clockwise. I've tried that too. The problem persists whether it be counter clockwise or clockwise.

Comment: Are you rounding / truncating the coordinates to integer in `tk_to_cart` and/or `cart_to_tk`?

Comment: Recall Pythagorean theorem and you'll do just fine

Comment: In any case, having the data flow in just one direction (from model to screen) rather than back-and-forth will probably help...

Comment: @sabik tk_to_cart and cart_to_tk are just two lines of addition / subtraction respectively. I think python with automatically convert them to floats when an float is added / subtracted to an integer

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong type? math.cos and math.sin need radians as arguments, so maybe you're using degrees?

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 I tried using pi/8 radians(not in the code snippet) and the issue persisted.

Comment: @sabik I also tried retrieving the current x and y coordinates of my line and then rotating them and line continued to get smaller

Comment: Yeah, don't retrieve them; always have the information flow in one direction. If that's still a problem, avoid rotating repeatedly; instead, increase the angle and always rotate from the original x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably loss of precision somewhere along the line, particularly if `tk_to_cart` and/or `cart_to_tk` round or truncate to integer.

A couple of ideas:

- have the data flow in just one direction (from model to screen) rather than back-and-forth; and, if that doesn't help,
- avoid rotating repeatedly, instead increase the angle and always rotate from the original `x` and `y`.

Something like:

```
def run(root, canvas, line, x_cart, y_cart, width, height, theta=0):
    # counter clockwise rotation of cartesian coordinates
    # X =  xcosθ + ysinθ
    # Y = -xsinθ + ycosθ

    theta += 1/8

    x_rot =  x_cart * cos(theta) + y_cart * sin(theta)
    y_rot = -x_cart * sin(theta) + y_cart * cos(theta)

    x_tk, y_tl = cart_to_tk(width/2, height/2, x_rot, y_rot)

    canvas.delete(line)
    line = canvas.create_line(width/2, height/2, x_tk, y_tk)

    root.after(20, lambda: run(root, canvas, line, x_cart, y_cart, width, height, theta))
```

Comment: Rotating from the original x and y solve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose this solution to make the line turn around a point.

#### The basic trigonometry

Refer to the following diagram

[image: trigonometric diagram]

You have your segment of a certain `length` going from point `x_o, y_o` to point `x_p, y_p`. Where `x_o, y_o` is the center of rotation of the segment and the origin of the translated frame of reference `x', y'` with respect with the `canva` frame of reference which is `x, y`.

Now, `x_o, y_o` and `length` are input data and **don't change over time** (unless you decide to).

Given that, with some trigonometry in `x', y'`:

```
x_p = length * cos(theta)
y_p = length * sin(theta)
```

Since your frame of reference is translated the above formulae becomes:

```
x_p = length * cos(theta) + x_o
y_p = length * sin(theta) + y_o
```

As you can see, you are calculating `x_p, y_p`, so length doesn't change here.

---

#### Translating into code

Let's express `theta` as a multiple of `math.pi` which is updated in the loop.

The method becomes:

```
def draw_line(root, canvas, length, x_o=0, y_o=0, theta=0.1, rotation='cw', line=None):
    if line is not None:
        canvas.delete(line)
    
    x_p = length * math.cos(math.pi * theta) + x_o
    y_p = length * math.sin(math.pi * theta) + y_o

    k = {'ccw': -1, 'cw': 1}[rotation]
    theta = theta + k * 0.05 # or any non linear function to change the motion

    line = canvas.create_line(x_o, y_o, x_p, y_p)
    root.after(100, lambda: draw_line(root, canvas, length, x_o, y_o, theta, rotation, line))
```

So, run for testing:

```
import tkinter
import math

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

length = 100
x_o = 100
y_o = 100
draw_line(root, canvas, x_o, y_o, length, rotation='ccw')
```

---

Using this basic trigonometric way it is easier to control the motion.

You can change the side of rotation `cw` or `ccw`. You can calculate theta with a non linear function to change the angular speed over time. You can add a speed parameter as argument. You can change `x_o, y_o` over time to make the line move around. Etc.